# Lexmark MS517dn prints very slow

Tags: printing, printer, lexmark-printer

I have a Lexmark MS517dn that it's used in production and it prints very slow (~5 sec/page). Is there any setting to increase the print speed?

Comment: How fast is the internal test page speed?  Is it networked? Try resetting the network connection (make sure of print flow to the printer).  How much memory is in the printer?  Limited memory may cause print jobs to queue up.

Comment: Also, for laser, the quality of the print changes the speed. Try using a print setting with less DPI.

Answer (score 0):

Laser printers will only reach their maximum print speed when you are printing multiple copies of the same page. If you print 10 copies of a page, copies 2 to 10 should print at the rate of 45 ppm (the printer's rated speed). That rated speed is at the printer's lowest resolution setting. If the printer supports multiple resolution settings, these can be selected in the driver. In your case, try 300 or 600 dpi instead of 1200.

Here are some of the other factors that affect print speed for the first copy of a page:

1. The size and complexity of the print job. This does not relate to the size of the document that is being printed. Instead, it's the size of the spool file that is important. To check, click the printer icon on the taskbar while a printjob is in progress.
2. Paper type. The rated speed only applies to bond paper. Most other types of paper (heavy paper, card, labels, etc) slow down the printer because the fuser has to apply more heat to the paper in order to melt the toner. Check the setting in the driver and the printer's web i/f or front panel menu.
3. The interface speed affects the rate at which the data can be sent to the printer. Make sure the printer is using a gigabit network connection.
4. Garbage can collect in the printer's non-volatile memory. Resetting the printer to factory defaults will clear that. The following procedure is from the [User Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/479353/Lexmark-Ms510.html?page=65#manual)

> Turn off the printer. Hold down 2 and 6 on the keypad while turning
>   the printer on. Release the buttons only when the screen with
>   the progress bar appears.The printer performs a power-on sequence, and
>   then the Configuration menu appears. When the printer is fully turned
>   on, a list of functions appears on the printer display. Press the up
>   or down arrow button until Wipe All Settings appears.The printer will
>   restart several times during this process.

Contrary to what many people think, printer memory has extremely little effect on print speed.